# Active record method to get all association records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a customers table and an orders table. Each customer has multiple orders and when I do a `Customers.all` I get all customers but not their orders. Is there a way to get `Customer.all.associations` as well?

**Getting:**

```
[
{
    : id=>1,
    : name=>"abc"
},
{
    : id=>2,
    : name=>"xyz"
}
```

]

***Want to get:***

```
[
{
    : id=>1,
    : name=>"abc",
    : orders=>[
        {
            : id=>1,
            : name=>"order1"
        },
        {
            : id=>2,
            : name=>"order2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    : id=>2,
    : name=>"xyz",
    : orders=>[
        {
            : id=>3,
            : name=>"order3"
        },
        {
            : id=>4,
            : name=>"order4"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: As some other answerers have said, you can use includes to lazy load relationships. But to get the output you're after, you'll probably have to use a serializer. This one might help https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get all Customer's orders, then

```
Customer.includes(:orders)
```

If you need to convert this into JSON or Hash format, then

```
Customer.includes(:orders).as_json(include: :orders)
```

Comment: Thanks Mayank! Worked.

Comment: One more request, I am also getting the `created_at` and `updated_at` date fields in the query.. How can I exclude them from the `:orders` module

Comment: You can use exclude in the as_json method.
`Customer.includes(:orders).as_json(except: [:created_at, :updated_at], include: :orders)`

Comment: If you also need to remove `created_at` and `updated_at` from the `orders` table, then you can use
`Customer.includes(:orders).as_json(except: [:created_at, :updated_at], include: [orders: {except: [:created_at, :updated_at]}])`

Answer (score 0):

```
@customers = Customer.includes(:orders)
@customers.as_json(include: :orders)
```

Comment: I don't even have to do `Customer.includes(:orders)` as my associations already describe that.. I want to just have `Customer.all.whatever.as_json` and that gives me entire json is that possible?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ You **need** `Customer.includes(:orders)` to avoid `N+1` query problem.